# How to quickly "cool down" from exercise before work?

Tags: personal-care

I go to the gym in the morning before heading to my office.  After I work out (especially cardio/aerobic exercise, but also just strength training) it takes me a long time to cool down.  I'll stretch, drink water, sit down and relax for 10 minutes, take a leisurely cool shower, and yet as much as an hour after I get out of the shower and get dressed, I'm still sweating.  It's especially noticeable on my head and back.

What can I do to speed this process up so I'm not sweating in the office half the morning?

Comment: Your body is in recovery.  Natural process after a good workout.

Comment: Perhaps not natural, as I don't think everyone experiences it.  I don't: after 10 minutes and a quick shower I wouldn't be sweating unless the office is overheated.  Maybe better asked on the physical fitness or health sites, where you'd get a better range of experience.

Comment: Weird. This doesn't happen to me, but drinking cold water is what i do after a workout.

Comment: I also have the same issue, but I started to use an "ice" shower gel by Rituals. I think it uses menthol or something, because you really get an icy/refreshing feeling once you get out of the shower.

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is the temporary increase in metabolic rate that goes with any exercise.  This requires your body to get rid of the greater amount of heat it's generating, and it can generally only do this by sweating.  You won't stop sweating in this way until your metabolism returns to your normal level.

One way to avoid sweating in the office is to build more time into your schedule between exercise and office -- end your workout an hour earlier, drink cool to very cold water afterward, and wait until your perspiration rate has dropped before showering -- and it goes without saying to shower in the coolest water that's comfortable, as hot water adds heat back to your body and promotes sweating.

Another idea is to exercise in the evening instead of the morning -- then cool off and shower before bed.  This will also save time in the morning, letting a slightly later bedtime compensate for the time you spend in the gym, cool down, and shower.

Answer (score 1):

I just run cold water from the tap over the underside of my wrists (where they meet the base of my thumb for a little while. It works very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for years now, here’s your 3-step solution:

1. Cold shower after workout
2. Buy a desk fan for your office ($10 on Amazon)
3. Drink ice water for at least 30 minutes - hold off on the office coffee until your body has cooled

This will definitely help, if not completely solve your problem